# Can you install a homebrew forumula without updating Xcode?

Tags: macos, xcode, homebrew

I am trying to install a homebrew formula, but it just tells me that I need to update Xcode. Everything worked correctly before and I can't install the update, first of all, my internet speed is very bad, and when I click update in the App Store it just says "waiting".

I tried reading the output of `brew help` and such but I couldn't find any "force" or similar option. Is it possible to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the file which prevents me from installing anything. It is `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/os/mac/diagnostic.rb`

What I did to solve this was commenting out lines 65-82 and then locking the file so it doesn't get overwritten.

Comment: How can I lock the file?

Comment: @IndOubt Mark the file, click command + I, from there you can lock it by checking a box